# nginx rewrite insert url in request : getting escaped

Tags: nginx, rewrite, proxypass

I am trying to rewrite an url using rewrite. I want to insert an url into the request uri but : which is part of http: is getting escaped and my app never gets the correct url. How do I prevent escaping of : while rewriting?

```
rewrite /(.*)url(.*) /$1http://example.com$2 break;
```

is resulting in;

```
/abc/http%3A//example.com/myfile.html
```

while it should be;

```
/abc/http://example.com/myfile.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The path component of URL cannot contain colons in unescaped form, that is why nginx escapes it. Only valid spot for colon is to separate protocol and domain or user/domain part of the URL.

You need to either leave the `http://` out of the path component, unescape it in your application or just add `http` / `https` as one component in the path, and change your application to add the colon.